Google sheet IFS formula no match error N/A
Please don't judge but I have to use this formula ( I  had to cut it shorter though as stackoverflow didn't allow me to post mostly code), however it gives the "N/A" No match error message.
And the formula bar is underlined, so I was wondering if there's a mistake in the syntax?
`=IFS(
'Backlog-2'!E5=111111112,"Potential Energy",
'Backlog-2'!E5=111111121,"Mechanical Strength",
'Backlog-2'!E5=111121112,"Mass and Velocity ➕ Potential Energy",
'Backlog-2'!E5=111121121,"Mass and Velocity ➕ Mechanical Strength",
'Backlog-2'!E5=111121122,"Mass and Velocity ➕ Mechanical Strength ➕ Potential Energy",
'Backlog-2'!E5=111122211,"Mass and Velocity ➕ Acceleration and Deceleration",
'Backlog-2'!E5=111122212,"Mass and Velocity ➕ Acceleration and Deceleration ➕ Potential Energy",
'Backlog-2'!E5=111122221,"Mass and Velocity ➕ Acceleration and Deceleration ➕ Mechanical Strength",
'Backlog-2'!E5=121221122,"Relative Location ➕ Mass and Stability ➕ Mass and Velocity ➕ Mechanical Strength ➕ Potential Energy")`

Can you please see what's wrong?

Your formula is correct. The message is clear enough that you don't have any matching value in E5 cell.

An answer has been posted in response to your question. Please review the answer if it correctly solves your issue. If it does, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and/or upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that their issue can be resolved. For further details, you may read the article on how to accept the answer.

Ifs Behaviour
Citing Harun24hr's comment, your formula as it is has no errors. The reason why you are getting an N/A or no match error is probably because your cell E5 does not contain a value that matches any of the values present in the condition part of your formula(lines like: !E5=111111121, !E5=111111112), or cell E5 contains no value at all.
Please note that the formula that you posted will check if cell E5 in the sheet named 'Backlog-2' contains any of the values given in your formula and then output the corresponding message/value. For example, if cell E5's value is '111111112', the output will be 'Potential Energy', if E5's value is '111111121', the output will be 'Mechanical Strength', and so on.
Reference: Google Sheets IFS function
